# Android NDK build issue with gnustl_shared

Tags: android, c++, c, build, android-ndk

I have a problem with my Android NDK Project.

My project consists of 2 projects: a library and an application.

I want to use gnustl_shared and have gnustl_shared.so in a resulting .apk file.

So I have APP_STL := gnustl_shared in both of my Application.mk files.

The problem is that if I do so it gives me the following error:

```
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so
Origin 1: /Volumes/STUFF/repos/trunk/android/MainActivity/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so
Origin 2: /Volumes/STUFF/repos/trunk/android/MyLib/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so
```

If I use APP_STL := gnustl_shared for one project only it builds, but links against static library (as it should, actually).

Does anyone know how to link agains gnustl_shared in both library and application and avoid this error? Any help or even clue is much appreciated.

Comment: Could we see the relevant parts from the .mk files in the application and the library which do the linking to the .so?

Comment: Basically they are nothing but: APP_PLATFORM := android-9 and APP_STL := gnustl_shared. Dependency is done through eclipse. Making dependency with eclipse is just easier in development phase to make it build dependencies every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. Select library project
2. Navigate to: Project->Properties->Java Build Path
3. Select "Order and Export" tab
4. Uncheck "Android Private Libraries" and "Android Dependencies"

They will anyway be added to the final .apk with the application config.

Comment: This does not work on ADT 23.0.4.1468518 and Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1).